# Cant execute script I own

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have a script called 'jupyter' in my home directory located in ~/.local/bin/ . Running

`ls -la`

I see:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 <user> <user>   218 Jun 12 11:26 jupyter`

where <user> is my username. However, when I execute

`./jupyter`

in the ~/.local/bin/ directory, I get the error:

`bash: ./jupyter: Permission denied`

I've ran both the commands

`chmod -R 777 /home/<user>/.local/bin`

`chown -R <user>:<user> /home/<user>/.local/bin`

I also get the same error for all other scripts in this directory. I ran the above commands as both the user  and as root via 'sudo'. Every script says I dont have the correct permissions even though I own them and I have the correct ACL's:

`getfacl jupyter`

output:

```
# file: jupyter 
# owner: <user>
# group: <user>
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Not sure why I am getting permission denied?

I am using Manjaro 21.2.6 executing the above commands in a bash shell. I've also tried executing in a TTY with identical results.

Edit:

Command:

`stat /home/<user>/.local/bin/jupyter`

Output:

```
  File: /home/<user>/.local/bin/jupyter
  Size: 218         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,5   Inode: 792902      Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  <user>)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:home_bin_t:s0
Access: 2022-06-17 20:49:46.263295064 +0200
Modify: 2021-06-17 16:57:50.736921826 +0200
Change: 2022-06-10 09:17:26.127764058 +0200
 Birth: 2021-06-17 16:57:50.736921826 +0200
```

Command:

`strace /home/<user>/.local/bin/jupyter`

Output:

https://pastebin.com/tPUqtM77

Comment: can you run `stat /home/<user>/.local/bin//jupyter` ?
as well as `strace /home/<user>/.local/bin//jupyter` ?

there can be multiple reasons for this apart from permission.
like file system corruption , user restriction by root ( different from permission) etc. 
can you try execute this from other directory preferably /bin or /usr/bin ? as you can execute ls by this user try placing where ls is (`which ls`).
And running hello world bash script from /home/<user>/.local/bin/. these are not solutions but debug steps collecting data

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the post with the info, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'execute from other directory'. Like move the jupyter script to the suggested directories? Or `cd` into the directory and run the command?

Answer (score 0):

The jupyter is actually a Python app. You need both the script and the python bin having execution permission. `cat /home/<user>/.local/bin/jupyter` to tell where the python bin locates.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install jupyter`

From strace log.

> write(2, "    from jupyter_core.command im"..., 42    from jupyter_core.command import main
> ) = 42
> write(2, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module n"..., 52ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_core'
> ) = 52

Which can cause because either

1. jupyter instlled
   OR
2. jupyter not instlled for python version used.

causing `jupyter_core` module not found.

it is using default version of python

> read(4, "#!/usr/bin/python\n# -*- coding: "..., 8192) = 218

which is using `/usr/bin/python` which is mostly symbolic link to python2.7 or python3.x

depending on that you need to use pip2.7 or pip3 to get jupyter working.

to verify test as following. ( in your case if jupyter is installed properly ther will not be any error.)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jupyter_core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core
>>>
```

Best way to install jupyter is anaconda. which you will find [anaconda docs linux install](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/)

but pip will do good as well.